# Response.Redirect to server path

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to re-direct employees on our network to a server path like so

```
Response.Redirect("\\Aus-file00\Public\Chili_Cookoff")
```

I have tried adding "file://" in front but it does not work.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect to network path. If you want to just open network folder try this, for example:

```
Response.Write("<script>document.location.href = 'file://Aus-file00/Public/Chili_Cookoff';</script>");
```

It opens new Explorer window from the network path. I tested it in IE only. I think this is only browser which supports things like that.